# How to remove className in react after certain time

Tags: reactjs

I'm using these codes to change my button component background to orange using classname but I want to remove classname after a second , what should I do?

```
let [Clicked,setState] = useState(false)
const Clicking =()=>{
setState(!Clicked)
}

return <Button text="dummytext" onClick={clicking} className={Clicked?btnClicked.bgChange:''}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `setTimeout` in `useEffect` hook in this way:

```
let [Clicked,setState] = useState(false)
const Clicking =()=>{
setState(!Clicked)
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (Clicked) setTimeout(() => setState(false), 1000)
}, [Clicked])

return <Button text="dummytext" onClick={clicking} className={Clicked?btnClicked.bgChange:''}/>
```

Comment: @IhateReact No problem, happy to help you. Have a nice coding =)